# How to access a site from a remote system in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

This is my first go at Sharepoint.

I have installed and configured Sharepoint 2013 in a Single VM according to the Hardware and Software Requirements.

Now I have created a site that has the following url:

```
http://win-5a8pp4v402g/sharepoint_test/site_1/
```

**win-5a8pp4v402g** is the part that got pre-pended on its own. It is the computer name.

I am running the Sharepoint Server on port 6666. Also the VM has a local IP assigned for the moment.

When I access the VM through Remote Desktop, and open the browser in the VM itself, the url above works fine obviously.

My problem is that I want to access this site from another system withing the same local network. I can access the Central Administration from the remote system using the **local_ip:6666**

But how do I access the site from the remote system?

I am asking because I want to use the Sharepoint REST API to do some tasks from the client side and until and unless I can access the site I cant really proceed. Some help here please? I am a little confused.

Comment: It mostly depends on your DNS settings and sharepoint alternate access mappings. Have you tried accessing your site by IP? If it does not work try to add alternate access mapping for ip adress.

Comment: Yes did something like that. Modified my hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moified `/etc/hosts` file by adding a mapping of the IP address of the VM in the remote system. Since the VM and the remote system are in the same domain, I did this in hosts file:

`local_ip win-5a8pp4v402g`

Comment: This is appropriate way to do this only for one computer. If you want it to work for all computers in network you need to configure DNS.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am only testing it right now. Once I get all the aspects working, I will map it to a FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

hi if you want configure dns server to all computers, how we can do that, can yop please give the steps,

you means adding the domain to the system or something else

To join CLIENT1 to the CORP domain
Click Start, right-click Computer, and then click Properties.
On the System page, click Advanced system settings.
In the System Properties dialog box, click the Computer Name tab. On the Computer Name tab, click Change.
In the Computer Name/Domain Changes dialog box, click Domain, type corp.contoso.com, and then click OK.
When you are prompted for a user name and password, type the user name and password for the User1 domain account, and then click OK.
When you see a dialog box that welcomes you to the corp.contoso.com domain, click OK.
When you see a dialog box that prompts you to restart the computer, click OK.
In the System Properties dialog box, click Close. Click the button that restarts the computer.
After the computer restarts, log on as CORP\User1.